# Is there a combination of foldLeft and for-yield?

Tags: scala, collections, yield, fold

I must handle with sequences of orders (here `Int` for simplification):

```
// the handleOrder methods are in fact much more complicated:
def handleOrders(prev: Double, orders: Seq[Int]): Double = prev + orders.sum
def handleOrder(prev: Double, order: Int): Double = prev / order
```

As a result from a so called

```
def nextGroup(prev: Double, orders: Seq[Int]): Seq[Double]
```

function I get a sequence of another class (here `Double` for simplification).

From this I've implemented two versions.

**Version 1 (foldLeft and explicit builder):**

```
def nextGroup1(prev: Double, orders: Seq[Int]): Seq[Double] = {
  import collection.mutable.Builder
  import collection.immutable.VectorBuilder
  val bld: Builder[Double, Seq[Double]] = new VectorBuilder[Double]
  var first = true
  orders.foldLeft(prev) { (prev, order) =>
    val step = if (first) handleOrders(prev, orders) else prev
    val next = handleOrder(step, order)
    first = false
    bld += next
    next
  }
  bld.result
}
```

**Version 2 (var and for yield builder):**

```
def nextGroup2(prev: Double, orders: Seq[Int]): Seq[Double] = {
  var first = true
  var präv = prev
  for (order <- orders) yield {
    if (first) präv = handleOrders(präv, orders)
    präv = handleOrder(präv, order)
    first = false
    präv
  }
}
```

I'd like to save either explicit builder in version 1 or mutable `var` in version 2.

Is this possible? Perhaps with a combination of `foldLeft` and `for`-`yield`?

**And still something sample data:**

```
val orders = Seq(1, 2, 3)
nextGroup1(1d, orders) // => Vector(7.0, 3.5, 1.1666666666666667)
nextGroup2(1d, orders) // => List(7.0, 3.5, 1.1666666666666667)
nextGroup1(2d, orders) // => Vector(8.0, 4.0, 1.3333333333333333)
nextGroup2(2d, orders) // => List(8.0, 4.0, 1.3333333333333333)
```

The `nextGroup` results handled as `Seq[Double]`, so `Vector` or `List` is no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
orders.tail.scanLeft(handleOrders(prev, orders)) { (p, o) => handleOrder(p, o) }
```

`scanLeft` does the same as `foldLeft` does but keeps all intermediate results. You can get rid of the special case by excluding the `head` of the collection which you can do using `orders.tail`.

Comment: Thank you, I like it! Has the `case` keyword a special meaning or is it just a matter of taste? Because `orders.tail.scanLeft(handleOrders(prev, orders)) { (p, o) => handleOrder(p, o) }` or even `orders.tail.scanLeft(handleOrders(prev, orders)) { handleOrder(_, _) }` does the job too.

Comment: You’re correct. It is not necessary to use `case`. I think I’ve written it out of habit (it is needed in more complicated matches). (`case` might even be a bit slower.)

Comment: I use the `(p, o) =>` version, though, to make it clearer which is which. In the end, it is a matter of taste indeed.